# hello i have a problem in my git remote how can i make it

Tags: node.js, git

```
$ git remote add origin <URL>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

> it gives me this error so how can I fix it please help me thanks!

Comment: Did you type `<URL>` literally? That's interpreted as an input redirection and an incomplete output redirection. You need to supply an actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

- git remote add origin . you should remove < > characters because they are used to indicate a place-holder.
- URL is your repo-url
- If git remote add origin [repo-url] doesn't help, try:
  git remote set-url origin [repo-url]